# Do I have to complete all the quests?

Tags: solatorobo-red-the-hunter

Can I complete the game just by doing the main story quests? Or do I have to do all of the side quests as well, to make sure my Hunter level is high enough for the story quests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Meow-Oui.* Yes to the latter question, but you can skip the ones you don't like on your later playthroughs (D: Oh Air Robo GP, how I loathe thee).

All quests are mandatory, but the order you complete them in is not. The WiFi/DLC quests (already preloaded on the NA versions) are optional. There should be ~80 quests or so.

It's suppose to give you the feel for the atmosphere of the game (such as the fun dialogues).

Don't miss out on the Tail Concerto cameos!

Comment: Argh. I hate Air Robo GP. >.<